# How to close popup only when clicked on mapview and not drag or pinch in android

Tags: android, google-maps, view, drag, pinch

I am working in Android 2.2. I have overlays on my MapView, each overlay market gets a popup window when clicked on.

I want to close the popup window when the MapView is tapped/clicked, but the normal code for doing this in the OnTouch event also closes it when it's dragged or pinched.

How do I handle a drag or pinch in the Ontouch event?

Comment: *"... I want to close the popup window only when..."* - don't you mean "I want to **open** the popup window"?

Comment: No I mean I want to **Close** the popup window which will be opened when I click on any of the overlay markers

Comment: I dont know is this is working...Why did I get down rated... + why is no one helping me

Comment: don't know, maybe because the question is not very understandable... at least to me.

Comment: Its simple...I am showing a popup window when I tap on a overlay marker on the map. I want that popup to be closed only when the mapview is taped and not when the mapview is dragged or pinched

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem here is, you're using the single-touch API, with Android 2.0+ you have the capabilities to use their multi-touch API.

You basically have to use the MotionEvent parameter in an overridden onTouch method, to get the exact motion, and then handle your code accordingly, based off event.

Here's a decent blog entry with a tutorial:

- [How to use Multi-touch in Android 2](http://blogs.zdnet.com/Burnette/?p=1747)
- [How to use Multi-touch in Android 2: Part 2, Building the Touch example](http://www.zdnet.com/blog/burnette/how-to-use-multi-touch-in-android-2-part-2-building-the-touch-example/1763?tag=content;siu-container)
- [How to use Multi-touch in Android 2: Part 3, Understanding touch events](http://www.zdnet.com/blog/burnette/how-to-use-multi-touch-in-android-2-part-3-understanding-touch-events/1775?tag=content;siu-container)